# Why does awk return an extra line and "0" after system call?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, awk

This awk script uses a system call to convert seconds to timecodes. Why not use a built-in function instead? For portability reasons. This needs to work on OS X Mavericks (GNU bash, version 3.2.53, awk version 20070501), for which the built-in strftime function isn't available (as far as I know).

```
cat file
A 3000
B 3010
C 3020
```

My script:

```
awk '{ printf "%s %s\n", system( "date -r " $2 " -j +%H:%M:%S" ), $1 }' file
```

returns this

```
01:50:00
0 A
01:50:10
0 B
01:50:20
0 C
```

while I'm trying to print the value of the first record on the same line as the timecode like so:

```
01:50:00 A
01:50:10 B
01:50:20 C
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If all versions of `awk` don't have the functionality you need, maybe you should be moving to Perl or Python (or something similar) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `date` command to print your literal value of `$1` like this:

```
awk '{ system( "/bin/date -r " $2 " -j \"+%H:%M:%S " $1 "\"" ) }' file
19:50:00 A
19:50:10 B
19:50:20 C
```

Or else use `getline` in awk:

```
awk '{ cmd = "/bin/date -r " $2 " -j +%H:%M:%S"; 
        if (cmd | getline var) printf "%s %s\n", d, $1; close (cmd) }' file
19:50:00 A
19:50:10 B
19:50:20 C
```

Comment: I was already using `date`. Your solution moves the field into the system call. It works, but I would prefer to keep it outside as the script will evolve and become more complex. Any alternative ideas?

Comment: Yes alternative idea is already in the answer using `getline` :)

Comment: @user2243670 Getline is the best option. Although there is still no need for printf just use `print d,$1`.

Comment: I don't understand the second solution in which you're not using `system()`. It works, though. Is this syntax more elliptical or is it a different approach altogether?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe

Comment: Learning a lot, thanks! Shouldn't the command be closed afterwards — as is done in the example? something like `close("date")`?

Comment: "can", so that's optional? Don't mean to be nitpicking, just being curious :)

Comment: I used `close("date")` but awk returns "makes too many open files" after 33 records. The original file has hundreds of records. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to close the **exact** string that you ran.

Comment: Yes you need to store while command in an awk variable and use same during variable for getline and close calls.

Comment: It needs to be `if (cmd | getline d)...` or you'll get the last valid date printed repeatedly if the input file contains an invalid date. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, that was very well written blog on `getline`. It is corrected now.